# Using Quantum Amplitude Estimation to find integral

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I am trying to use the Quantum Amplitude Estimation (QAE) algorithm to find the numerical integral of `sin^2(x)` in the range `[0, /4]` using Qiskit. I understand that I need to encode the problem, create a quantum oracle, use the Grover operator, perform QAE, and post-process the result. However, I'm not sure how to encode the function to begin with. How to define the oracle for this? Any pointers would be of great help!

```
# load libraries
import numpy as np  
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer  
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram  
  
# encoding the function
def encode_problem(circuit, qubits):
    # how to encode the function?
    for qubit in qubits:  
        circuit.h(qubit)  
  
# oracle for f(x) = sin^2(x)  
def quantum_oracle(circuit, qubits, output_qubit):  
    # quantum oracle for sin^2(x)  
    pass  
  
# Grover operator  
def grover_operator(circuit, qubits, output_qubit):  
    for qubit in qubits:  
        circuit.h(qubit)  
        circuit.x(qubit)  
    circuit.cz(qubits[0], output_qubit)  
    for qubit in qubits:  
        circuit.x(qubit)  
        circuit.h(qubit)  
  
# qae
def qae(circuit, qubits, output_qubit, num_iterations):  
    for _ in range(num_iterations):  
        quantum_oracle(circuit, qubits, output_qubit)  
        grover_operator(circuit, qubits, output_qubit)  
  
# no. of qubits and ancilla  
qubits = 3  
ancilla = 1  
qc = QuantumCircuit(qubits + ancilla, qubits)  
  
# encode, run qae
encode_problem(qc, list(range(qubits)))  
qae(qc, list(range(qubits)), qubits, num_iterations=1)
  
# Measurement  
qc.measure(list(range(qubits)), list(range(qubits)))  
  
# simulate the circuit  
qasm_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')  
job = execute(qc, qasm_sim, shots=8192)

# retrieve the counts of the measurement outcomes
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc1)

# plot the histogram of the counts
plot_histogram(counts)
```

Comment: Before diving into coding how do you see QAE being applied to integrating the function? Can you express what you want to achieve mathematically?